# What's wrong with my masking in this ImageMeasurements?

Tags: image-processing

I want to find the mean color of an image's region defined by a polygon, and I tried this:

```
lena = Import["lena.tif"]
poly = Polygon[{{10, 10}, {120, 10}, {100, 100}}];

imgDim = ImageDimensions[lena];
imgBounds = Transpose[{{0, 0}, imgDim}];
mask = Image[Graphics[{White, poly}, Background -> Black, 
             ImageSize -> imgDim, PlotRange -> imgBounds]]

ImageMeasurements[lena, Masking -> mask, "Mean"]
```

But when I run this I get an error

```
ImageMeasurements: Masking -> [the mask image] is not a known image measurements property.
```

ImageMeasurements takes the Masking option, so I expected there was something wrong with my masking image. But changing to `Masking -> All` still gives the same error. Is the documentation wrong?
(I'm on version 11.2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works well:

```
poly = Polygon[{{10, 10}, {120, 10}, {100, 100}}];

ImageMeasurements[lena, "Mean", Masking -> poly]
```

`Masking` requires the graphical primitive instead your image. The sequence of arguments in `ImageMeasurements` have to be [image, measured value, options]. It does not work otherwise.

Comment: OMG, now you make me look so dumb :-). Thanks for the tip.